# Using multivalued field in map function

Tags: solr

I'm working on implementing Solr in a project and right now I'm stuck on a specific search including an arr field. The thing is:

I'd like to search sub-id's on an object, these sub-id's are stored in a multivalue field, e.g.:

```
<arr name="SubIds">
   <int>12272</int>
   <int>12304</int>
   <int>12306</int>
</arr>
```

The query (or part of the query) that I want to use is as follows:
map(SubIds,i,i,1,0)

When I, for example, fill 12304 on the 'i' space in the map function above, I would expect my function to return 1. If I would enter 12345 it should return 0. The thing is that when I run this query it returns 0, or "There's no number 12304 in this field, I return 0".

When removing the 0 from my map function I can see the actual value returned to me (when 12304 return 1, when different return value), in this case that's 12306! I've tried this with some different multivalued fields but the result is the same; it looks like the function is checking the last value in the multivalue field against my filled in ID.

Is this true? And when it does, is there any way in looking through the whole arr and only return 0 when the value doesn't exist in the whole multivalued field?

** *Edit: It's just a hunch, but could it be that the map() function automatically orders the arr list when it sees that all the items are of type int (for example). That could mean that the map returns the first number (the highest) which would (in my example) be 12306, not 12304...**

Thanks!

Comment: What is this map() function ?? who implemented, and what query is making to SOLR ? Your're using faceting to count the values in SubIds?  
Can you share this map function ?

Comment: It's the standard map function that one can use to query... For more info on map(), check the official site: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#map

Comment: The complete query to SOLR is as follows:
?q={!func}map(SubIds,12304,12304,1,0)&fl=*,score&sort=score%20desc

And what do you mean by saying that I use faceting to count the values in SubIds? Is there a way to do a sum on the different values in the SubIds arr? That would save my day...

Comment: I didn't used map function until now, maybe this is the default behavior when working with multivalue fields. Try using faceting by range. It will count how many documents have values in the range. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range

Comment: facet.range=SubIds&f.SubIds.facet.range.start=12304&facet.range.include=lower

Comment: The problem is that the search is a little bit more complex. I'm using a sum on two different map functions (the one above included), the sum is important for the sort order in my search, the first argument is the most important and second the outcome from the map above...

Is there anybody who nows how the map function works on a multivalued field? I find it hard to get some relevant documentation about the topic...

Answer (score 1):

... It looks like function queries don't work with multivalued fields ...

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Using-multivalued-field-in-map-function-td3318843.html#a3322023:

> Function queries don't work with multivalued field.
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Vector_Functions

Given the following case, is there anybody who has a better idea on how I can query the wanted data?

> I've got a website full of blogposts and every blogpost has an owner,
>   this owner is refererred to through his/her id. For example: BloggerId
>   = 123. It's also possible that the blog has multiple co-writers, which
>   are also referred to by there BloggerId but these id's are stored in
>   the multivalue field, in my previous example SubIds.
>
> When searching for a specific blogger one searches the BloggerId.
>   Searchresults are influenced by a number of variables, the
>   country/state/more specific geological data, the blogcategory, etc.
>   For this I use a facetted query. Next I want to make some results more
>   important, depending on the BloggerId, I tried to do this with the
>   following query:
>
> ?q={!func}map(sum(map(BloggerId,12304,12304,2,0),map(BloggerId,12304,12304,1,0)),3,3,2)&fl=*,score&facet.field=Country&f.Country.facet.limit=6&facet.field=State&fq=(BlogCategory:internet%20OR%20BlogCategory:sports&sort=score%20desc,Top%20desc,%20SortPriority%20asc&start=0&omitHeader=true
>
> In the resulting list, blogs written by BloggerId 12304 should be on
>   top of the list, followed by the blogs where BloggerId 12304 was
>   co-writer. After that, all other blogs that follow the criteria but
>   aren't written (or co-written) by BloggerId 12304.

Maybe I could make this multivalued field a string field (where id's are seperated by ";") and query my value, but if one has a better idea your always welcome!

**In the end I chose to add a string valued field with whitespaces to seperate the different values. After that I used the solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory class to quickly scan the string for occurences of a specific ID.**